# Generate dynamic columns in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, angularjs

I need make in Angular table which will be generate dynamic numbers of column, but the number of column I need loading form data base and this information will be display number of columns which will be generated, and then will be loading date form another table in data base to this table (in HTML) but I need to load data only from 6 column to number which I was written about it at the beginning of this comment.

I know I need use ng-repeat on tr, td and write custom filter which display range columns on site, but I don't know how this all merge? How transfer from database (API) number which i use like variable and then add to filter where I use in for loop and then add this to view page where will be display beautiful table with data which I want?

Picture of the output you can see [here.](http://sinke.vot.pl/testy/angular-table.jpg)

My code so far - controller.js:

```
'use strict';

var pokayokaCtr = angular.module( 'pokayokaCtr' , [ 'ngRoute' ] );



// -------------------------------------------
//                  DRAWINGS
// -------------------------------------------

pokayokaCtr.controller( 'drawings' , [ '$scope' , '$http', function( $scope, $http ){


    $http.get( 'api/admin/drawings/get' ).
    success( function( data ){
        $scope.drawings = data;
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Błąd pobrania pliku z bazy danych! Drawings' );
    });

}]);

pokayokaCtr.controller( 'drawingCreate' , [ '$scope' , '$http' , '$timeout', function( $scope , $http, $timeout){

    $scope.createDrawing = function ( drawing ) {


        $http.post('api/admin/drawings/create', {
            drawing : drawing
        }).success(function(){

            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.success = false;

                $scope.drawing = {};
            } , 1500 );
            console.log($scope.drawing);

        }).error(function(){
            console.log('Error database connect!')
        });

    };

}]);


pokayokaCtr.controller( 'pokayokes' , [ '$scope' , '$http', '$routeParams', function( $scope, $http, $routeParams ){

    var pokayokeName = $routeParams.name;
    $scope.name = pokayokeName;

    $http.get( 'api/admin/pokayokes/get/' + pokayokeName ).
    success( function( data ){
        $scope.pokayokes = data;
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Error database connect!' );
    });

}]);

// pokayokaCtr.filter('rangeFilter', function() {
//       return function(input, total) {
//      total = parseInt(total);
//      for (var i=6; i<=total; i++)
//        input.push(i);
//      return input;
//   };
// });
```

View page:

```
<div id="page-wrapper" ng-controller="pokayokes">
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br>
                <div class="flat-panel">
                    <div class="flat-panel-header">
                        <h2 class="page-header" ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes | limitTo: 1"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i> Drawing number: {{ pokayoke.nazwa_rys }}</span></h2>

                    </div>
                    <div class="flat-panel-body">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning"  href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit name</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="delete(drawing, $index)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- /.row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="flat-panel">
                    <div class="flat-panel-header">
                                <h2 class="pull-left">Articles in drawing</h2>
                                <a ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes | limitTo: 1" class="pull-right btn btn-primary"  href="#/admin/article/create/part1/{{ pokayoke.nazwa_rys}}" style="margin: 20px 0 15px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add new article</a>                             
                    </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="flat-panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No.</th>
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                    <th>Article name <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </th>
                                    <th>Colors in article</th>
                                    <th ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes">{{$index}}</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes" >
                                    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                    <td><a href=""> <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> View</a></td>
                                    <td>{{pokayoke.nazwa_art}}</i> </td>
                                    <td>{{pokayoke.kolory_art}}</td>
                                    <td ng-repeat="num in pokayoke" >{{ num }}</td>   

                                </tr>                               
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div> <!-- responive -->
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->

</div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->
```

And output what I have now: [here](http://sinke.vot.pl/testy/output.jpg)
I want only first 4 columns and columns where are 'x'. 
I don't know how write filter.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can't eat an elephant all in one bite. You need to get some of this started yourself then present your code when you run into problems. Question is far too broad and needs to be more about specifics